# PHP Email script for Multi-Step Contact Form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, multi-step

I'm using this multi-step contact form: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar

Unfortunately, it will not send an email.

My form is the same as the example above. The only difference is I've modified the opening form tag to this:

```
<form id="msform" method="post" action="/mailer.php">
```

This is what my mailer.php looks like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$to = "me@mydomain.com";
$subject = "Submission from Multi-Step Form";
$message = "Name: ".$name."</br>Email: ".$email."</br>pass: ".$pass;

$headers = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);  
}
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` if you are not seeing any.

Comment: @HenryTK -- Unfortunately I'm not seeing any error messages, even with error_reporting set.